# Objective C, NSDictionary loop through each object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, facebook-graph-api, xcode4, nsdictionary

I am new to Facebook Developer. I want to create Mac OSX application using Facebook API. When i request FQL and its return me JSON data only like below:

My Code:

```
[self.result_text setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[result objectForKey: @"result"]];
```

It display:

```
[{"name":"My Name","first_name":"My First Name","last_name":"My Last Name"}]
```

I want to read the object inside this Dictionary. Example I just want to display "My Name" string. But I don't know how to it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

As Ashley Mills wrote, you should check the documentation. You can loop through the all dictionary keys like this:

```
for ( NSString *key in [dictionary allKeys]) {
  //do what you want to do with items
  NSLog(@"%@", [dictionary objectForKey:key]);
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This is also necessary for looping through a dictionary with NSNumber keys, i.e. for (NSNumber *key in [dictionary allKeys]) {

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) to transform the JSON string into a dictionary:

```
 NSDictionary *resultsDictionary = [resultString
      objectFromJSONStringWithParseOptions:JKParseOptionLooseUnicode|JKParseOptionValidFlags error:&err];

NSString* name = [resultDictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
```

JSONKit is straightforward to use and will make your application work also on older SDK versions.

Comment: oh, one thing I just noticed... the original poster is talking about a MacOS X application, not iOS (e.g. iOS 4 & iOS 5).

Comment: @Michael Dautermann: you are right; I only checked the tags for the OS... will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the JSON contents from the server into a NSDictionary object via Lion's brand new [NSJSONSerialization class](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (documentation linked for you).

e.g.

```
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [self.result_text dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding] options: nil error: &error];
```

And once you have it in a NSDictionary object, it's easy to do something like:

```
NSString * myLastNameContent = [jsonDictionary objectForKey: @"last_name"];
```

Sergio's answer (which he keeps editing, even as I type :-) is very good too.  +1 to him.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation for `NSDictionary` here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsdictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html

in particular the section titled **Accessing Keys and Values**